# Getting kex_exchange_identification prompt with ssh to github

Tags: git, ssh

Getting the following message with `git pull`:

```
$ git pull
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've tried changing the config for ssh to use port 443 to connect but it doesn't work. The result of `ssh -vT git@github.com` is the following:

```
% ssh -vT git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /.ssh/config
debug1: /.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: /.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 443.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.6
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by 20.205.243.166 port 443
```

ssh config:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Tried editing the ssh config as instructed by other answers but did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh to another host and got the following error:

```
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to [some ip] port 22: Operation timed out
```

Switched to another wifi with everything unchanged and my ssh went back to normal.

Comment: Good feedback. A "Connection closed by remote host" error often means a network issue of some kind, so it makes sense using a different one can help.

Comment: Damn, I've been stuck in this problem for two days, and it's normal after switching the network

Answer (score 1):

I you want to use SSH over HTTPS, you would need an SSH config file like:

```
Host github.com
    HostName ssh.github.com
    User git
    Port 443
```

You need to use the right hostname.